# How to detect all GPU/CPU transfers in pytorch?

Tags: performance, debugging, pytorch, gpu

I have a large pytorch project. How do I check if the project is performing any unexpected transfers of data from the GPU to the CPU or back?

As I understand it, GPU/CPU transfers are very costly for performance, and they can easily happen by accident if you are not very careful with your code. For example, calling `.item()` on a tensor on the GPU will cause that tensor to be transferred back to CPU, while blocking CPU execution.

Since there are a lot of ways to do this by accident, I need a reliable way to get all places in my code where data is transferred, so that I can prevent costly performance losses.

Ideally, I would be able to specify a section of code with a Context Manager that says "GPU/CPU transfers are allowed inside this block only. Any attempt to transfer data between GPU and CPU outside of this block causes an error."

Comment: [gpu profilers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#tools) can do this, excluding your last paragraph, although you can include or exclude sections from profiling, which might be more or less equivalent